# Unable to connect to Azure SQL from Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have setup a new Azure SQl and Azure Data Factory resource under the same Azure resource group.

However, I am unable to connect to Azure SQL from Azure Data Factory. I was able to do this in my previous place.

I am getting the error message below when I try to connect to Azure SQL from Azure Data Factory.

> ErrorCode=SqlFailedToConnect,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Cannot
> connect to SQL Database. Please contact SQL server team for further
> support. Server: 'xxxxxxxxxx.database.windows.net', Database:
> 'xxxxxxxxx', User: 'xxxxxxx'. Check the linked service configuration
> is correct, and make sure the SQL Database firewall allows the
> integration runtime to
> access.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Cannot
> open server 'sqlserver-represent-prod' requested by the login. Client
> with IP address '51.xxx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to access the server.
> To enable access, use the Azure Management Portal or run
> sp_set_firewall_rule on the master database to create a firewall rule
> for this IP address or address range.  It may take up to five minutes
> for this change to take effect.

However, when I add the firewall rule for the IP address in Azure SQL Server connectivity, it works. After a while I am getting the same error message but with a different IP address. In my previous place, I ddint have to add the firwall rule and it worked fine.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tick the check box "Allow Azure Services and Resources to access this server" under Exceptions.

You can find this option under Firewall rules.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add an exception in the azure portal to resolve this error.

In the Azure portal, under database server > security > networking , Add this exception as shown in the picture.

[image]